# How do I localise my windows based program

Tags: c#

I use one combobox that the user can choose to have English or farsi. And change the language with the button1 click.But sometimes this language change does not work properly.

What I have tried:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo cul;
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        cul = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        Properties.Settings.Default.lan = "en";
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
    else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        cul = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
        Properties.Settings.Default.lan = "fa";
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
    Application.Restart();
}
```

And in the program I wrote the following commands :

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo cu;
    if (Properties.Settings.Default.lan == "fa")
        cu = new CultureInfo("fa-R");
    else
        cu = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cu;
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cu;
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Comment: `fa-R` or `fa-IR` ?

Comment: Can you describe the problem you are experiencing (more than "sometimes it doesn't work properly")?

Comment: When I debug the app, and when the button clicks the first time,After other clicks, the language changes correctly